# Use strcpy to transform a C++ string to a Char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strcpy

For some reason, I was trying to covert a C++ string to a char array. Below is what I did:

```
string aS="hello world";
char aC[aS.size()];
strcpy(aC, aS.c_str());
cout << aC[0] << endl;

string bS="veooci  m eode owtwolwwwwtwwj mooawee mdeeme  eeeec eme aemmeledmll llllleolclclcmslococecewaccocmelaeaccoaaooojutmjooooocoemoooealm omjcdmcmkemmdemmmiwecmcmteeeote eoeeeem   ecc e  yolc e w    dtoooojttttmtwtt ttjcttoowl otdooco ko mooooo  aowmemm o  et  jmc    cmlctmmcccjcccecomatocooccoeoclooomoecwooo mcdoo dcdco dddooedoemod eddeedoedje  emadleweemeeedeeeec   or o  m  wejeetoj    o ojjjlwdjjjj mjmceaeoaai laaadoaa aetmotaemmj  mmmmmmlmm cmol c  mwoaoe omav";

char bC[bS.size()];
strcpy(bC, bS.c_str());
cout << aC[0] << endl;
```

When aC[0] was first called, it gave 'h' as expected. However, when aC[0] is called at the second time, it gave ''. Could someone explain me what happened here?

Comment: `char aC[aS.size()];` is not standard C++ (array dimensions need to be constant expressions, you could use `new` instead).

Answer (score 6):

> For some reason, I was trying to covert a C++ string to a char array

Why don't you just use [`.c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str), it does this for you

```
string aS="hello world";
cout << aS.c_str();
```

Answer (score 4):

`char aC[aS.size()];`

would need to be:

`char aC[aS.size() + 1];`

in order to allow for the terminating `'\0'` required for a C string.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the `std::string::c_str()` member function, you should then allocate the char array dynamically, as you cannot declare variable length arrays in C++, such as:

```
char* bC = new char[aS.size() + 1]; // don't forget to delete[]
strcpy(bC, bS.c_str());
```

Comment: May I know how to get the size of bC? Since it is a pointer, sizeof() does not work.

Comment: @Justdon'train I thought you want to "copy" the string into `bC`. Why do you need to get its size?

Comment: I wanna to do some stuff for each character.

Comment: @Justdon'train well the size of it is simply the size of the string you copied, i.e. `aS.size() + 1 `. You can also use `strlen(bC)` to get the size, since it is a C-string.

Comment: yes. just for curiosity, if we are given a pointer that points to an array, is there a way to get its size?

Comment: @Justdon'train The size of the array? No, unless there is some special delimiter (such as '\0' in case of C-strings)

Answer (score 1):

I can see some utility of changing to an array if you're calling a function that will change the string buffer (pre C++11).  Otherwise, use the other solutions such as `c_str()` if the buffer is not going to be changed.

However, if you really wanted a char array due to the buffer possibly being changed, use `std::vector<char>`.  This will bypass the issue of using non-standard syntax (`aC[aS.size()]`), and removes the need to dynamically allocate memory.  A `std::vector<char>` effectively *is* a changeable string buffer, only wrapped.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string aS="hello world";
    std::vector<char> aC(aS.begin(), aS.end());  // copy
    aC.push_back(0);  // null-terminate
    cout << &aC[0] << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
hello world
```

Now, where you need to specify a character array pointer, you just pass the address of the first element in the vector (provided that the vector is not empty).

Live Example: http://ideone.com/tF32Zt